# Link dependencies of a c# library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5

I have project `B`depending on project `A` which is a library that has it's own dependencies.

In project `A` I reference the assemblies that define `Dependency1Base<T>` and `Dependency2Class`, and define `MyClass` like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass: Dependency1Base<Dependency2Class>
    {
    }
}
```

In project `B`, I just reference project `A` and try to instance `MyClass`

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class B
    {
        public void main ()
        {
            var myInstance = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Project `A` builds fine, but when I try to build project `B`, I get an error telling me that `Dependency1Base` and `Dependency2Class` are defined in an assembly that is not referenced. So I'm wondering if there is a way to link this definitions in project `A` so that I don't have to add those references to project `B`? or do I always need to reference the dependencies of project `A` in any other project that uses `MyClass`?

Comment: Why you don't want to add reference in Project `B`?

Comment: The fact that `MyClass` inherits from `Dependency1Base<Dependency2Class>` is part of the public interface of `MyClass` - so if you want to use `MyClass`, you need to reference the assembly where `Dependency1Base` and `Dependency2Class` are defined.

Comment: @Blorgbeard so, to use a class defined in a referenced assembly I always need to reference all the assemblies that define its ancestor classes?

Comment: In most situations, both `Dependency1Base` and `Dependency2Class` are going to influence things like what *methods* `MyClass` has inherited, and the data types of some arguments and return values. How do you think the compiler can tell, in general, whether code you're writing is valid if it doesn't have access to those classes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to reference everything class or object you use in your project. But you don't have to reference more than that.

If you have a class `C` that inherits from `B`, which itself inherits from `A` :

In `C`, you must reference `B`, and if you use some properties or method that come from `A`, you must reference `A` as well

In `B`, you must reference `A`

In `A, you don't have to reference anything.